# How to specify an int from another class

Tags: java, actionlistener

This is going to be a embarrassing question but I'm new to Java.
I have a class that implements `ActionListener` with this code in it:

```
public class Shop1 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        int alis = 0;
        alis++;
        System.out.println(alis);
    }
}
```

Everytime I press the button it shows `1`.  I know that everytime I press the button it sets the integer to `0`, and adds `1`, but I tried to put the integer outside the class but this time it doesn't recognize the `int`.

Comment: What do you mean by "i tried to put the integer outside the class?"

Comment: You need to be precise. Show us the code that doesn't work. And tell us **how** it doesn't. Paste the exact and complete error message.

Comment: there is no error i just forgot how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing here (the variables is always 0) is caused by the variables *scope*.

In Java, variables have *block-scope*, meaning that they are valid only in the block (and any blocks in that block) that they where created in. A simple example:

```
public void scope1(){
    if (something){
        int myint = 1;
        // possibly some other code here...
    }
    System.out.println(myint); // This will not compile, myint is not known in this scope!
    int myint = 1; // Declare myint in this scope
    System.out.println(myint); // now it works.
}
```

As you can see here, the first `myint` is declared in the if-blocks *scope*, causing it to not be valid outside the if-block. The second definition of `myint` is valid for the entire method-block (after the line it was created in).

Back to your problem: The variable you're creating has a block-scope of the `actionPerformed()`-method. Therefore, when that method returns, the variable will no longer be valid and it's value will be gone. When you enter the method again, you create a new variable in that scope.

To handle it the way you want, move the variable "up" to a scope higher than the method. Id'd suggest doing so in `Shop1`:

```
public class Shop1 implements ActionListener{

    private int alis;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        alis++; // the variable is defined in the classes scope, so the values is "kept"
        System.out.println(alis);
    }

}
```

If anything is unclear, please comment!